Roslyn code fix: create method with single-line comment
I'm new to Roslyn code fixes and try to create a properly formatted (indentation, line breaks) empty method with just a single-line comment:
BEFORE:
public class Bla
{
    public void Blub()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

AFTER:
public class Bla
{
    public void Blub()
    {
        // I told you so
    }
}

I'm almost there, but I'm always missing a small piece. Here are my attempts:
v1 - Add comment via WithStatements
Code:
private static async Task<Document> RemoveContainOfDownMethod(Document document, BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax downMethodDeclaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SyntaxTree? documentSyntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (documentSyntaxTree == null || downMethodDeclaration.Body == null)
    {
        return document;
    }

    var commentTrivia = SyntaxFactory.Comment("// I told you so.");
    var emptyBlock = SyntaxFactory.Block()
        .WithOpenBraceToken(downMethodDeclaration.Body.OpenBraceToken)
        .WithCloseBraceToken(downMethodDeclaration.Body.CloseBraceToken)
        .WithStatements(SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<StatementSyntax>(
            SyntaxFactory.EmptyStatement().WithLeadingTrivia(commentTrivia)));

    CompilationUnitSyntax newDocument = documentSyntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(cancellationToken)
        .ReplaceNode(
            downMethodDeclaration.Body,
            emptyBlock
                .WithLeadingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetLeadingTrivia())
                .WithTrailingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetTrailingTrivia()));

    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newDocument);
}

Gives:
public class Bla
{
    public void Blub()
    {
        // I told you so                                        ;
    }
}

Flaw:

Trailing semicolon

v2 - Adding comment via WithCloseBraceToken
Code:
private static async Task<Document> RemoveContainOfDownMethod(Document document, BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax downMethodDeclaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SyntaxTree? documentSyntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (documentSyntaxTree == null || downMethodDeclaration.Body == null)
    {
        return document;
    }

    SyntaxTrivia commentTrivia = SyntaxFactory.Comment("// I told you so");
    BlockSyntax emptyBlock = SyntaxFactory.Block()
            .WithOpenBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenBraceToken))
            .WithCloseBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken).WithLeadingTrivia(commentTrivia));

    CompilationUnitSyntax newDocument = documentSyntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(cancellationToken)
        .ReplaceNode(
            downMethodDeclaration.Body,
            emptyBlock
                .WithLeadingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetLeadingTrivia())
                .WithTrailingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetTrailingTrivia()));

    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newDocument);
}

Gives:
public class Bla
{
    public void Blub()
    {
        // I told you so        }
}

Flaw:

Missing linebreak before closing curly brace of Blub

v3 Adding comment via WithCloseBraceToken with NormalizeWhitespace
Code:
private static async Task<Document> RemoveContainOfDownMethod(Document document, BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax downMethodDeclaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SyntaxTree? documentSyntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (documentSyntaxTree == null || downMethodDeclaration.Body == null)
    {
        return document;
    }

    SyntaxTrivia commentTrivia = SyntaxFactory.Comment("// I told you so");
    BlockSyntax emptyBlock = SyntaxFactory.Block()
            .WithOpenBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenBraceToken))
            .WithCloseBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken).WithLeadingTrivia(commentTrivia));

    CompilationUnitSyntax newDocument = documentSyntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(cancellationToken)
        .ReplaceNode(
            downMethodDeclaration.Body,
            emptyBlock
                .WithLeadingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetLeadingTrivia())
                .WithTrailingTrivia(downMethodDeclaration.Body.GetTrailingTrivia()))
        .NormalizeWhitespace();

    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newDocument);
}

Gives:
public class Bla
{
    public void Blub()
    {
    // I told you so
    }
}

Flaw:

Wrong indentation of comment


Looking here, you're missing an EndOfLineTrivia? I'm not sure why NormalizeWhitespace isn't catching it, though

And how can I add the EndOfLineTrivia as an additional trivia?

WithLeadingTrivia takes a SyntaxTrivia[] -- pass SyntaxFactory.LineFeed. https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net is very useful for problems like this, too

Thank you very much, that solved my issue  feel free to provide it as an answer so that I can upvote it

Using SharpLab to see the desired syntax tree, we can see that you're missing an EndOfLineTrivia after your CommentTrivia.
You should pass both to .WithLeadingTrivia:
    SyntaxTrivia commentTrivia = SyntaxFactory.Comment("// I told you so");
    BlockSyntax emptyBlock = SyntaxFactory.Block()
            .WithOpenBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenBraceToken))
            .WithCloseBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken)
                .WithLeadingTrivia(commentTrivia, SyntaxFactory.LineFeed));

Roslyn Quoter is a great tool for generating syntax tree-generation code from C# code.
